# XML data from webpage to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to allow users to enter a bunch of configuration parameters and format that to xml and upload an xml file.

I would construct the xml in javascript and send it to the server via xmlhttprequest object of ajax(requesting a php page).

How to I put all this data into the POST so that php can read it?

I have code that can shove all the info into the POST and send it to the php page. I just do not know how php can read it as raw data rather than name, value pairs.

Additionally I need to be able to upload xml document in the same format to the same php page.

Comment: This seems to work---<?php


echo file_get_contents("php://input");


?>

Comment: maybe `php://input` can be useful

Comment: try to send your data as plain text then do everything at php side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```